# I want to get all SPL tokens that are created and have some metadata

Tags: spl-token, metaplex

Earlier this was done through Solana token registry, although since its shut down what is the new way of fetching the latest tokens

Answer (score 0):

1. Aggregate mint accounts from onchain.
2. Get metadata from onchain for aggregated mint accounts.
3. Keep track of token program transaction history and parse create_token transactions to get newly created mint addresses seamlessly.

However, the easist way to get available tokens is to use 3rd party apis.
https://api.cryptorank.io/v0/coins?platformKeys=solana